# I cannot manage to export coordinates to a shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

This is the test code I have written:

```
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.poly(parts=[[[1,5],[5,5],[5,1],[3,3],[1,1]]])
w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
w.record('First','Polygon')
w.save('shapefiles/test/polygon')
```

However, it does not work and I am prompted with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\src\Python\coordinates.py", line 33, in <module>
    w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT) #shapefile.POLYGON)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 1293, in __init__
    self.shp = self.__getFileObj(os.path.splitext(target)[0] + '.shp')
  File "C:\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get that code from? It appears to relate to an older version of the `shapefile` module. Always check the documentation corresponding to your version. The latest docs are here:

https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#writing-shapefiles

and show that you create a `Writer` the the target file name and then `close` it to save the shapefile. This is the current way of what you are doing:

```
>>> w = shapefile.Writer('shapefiles/test/testfile')
>>> w.poly([[[1,5],[5,5],[5,1],[3,3],[1,1]]])
>>> w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
>>> w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
>>> w.record('First','Polygon')
>>> w.close()
```

Which produces a shapefile like this:

```
INFO: Open of `shapefiles/test/testfile.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: testfile
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2020-12-14
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (1.000000, 1.000000) - (5.000000, 5.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
FIRST_FLD: String (40.0)
SECOND_FLD: String (40.0)
OGRFeature(testfile):0
  FIRST_FLD (String) = First
  SECOND_FLD (String) = Polygon
  POLYGON ((1 5,5 5,5 1,3 3,1 1,1 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the code from the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/1.2.1/

Comment: And is that the version you have installed? Or is it version 2.something?

Comment: Your solution worked, so I think I have the latest version

Comment: @Carl 1.2.1 is from 2014, latest is 2.1.2 https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/#history